# how can i know what is the result of the non-void function without executing it

Tags: c++, visual-c++

the problem that in the main body the getwhattheywant function is executing twice what I want is this
getwhattheywant execute then the user entered one then if the user entered one do the summation operation but what is happening with me that it's reasking the user to enter a number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double dothesum(int x, int y)
{
    int sum = x + y;
    return sum;
};
int getwhatheywant()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "1- for sum " << endl;
    cout << "2- for quit ";
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}
void the_sum()
{
    int x, y;
    cout << " enter the first number " << endl;

    cin >> x;
    cout << " enter the second number " << endl;
    cin >> y;

    cout << " the sum of the two number is " << dothesum(x, y) << endl;
}

int main()
{

    int;

    while (getwhatheywant() != 2) {
        if (getwhatheywant() == 1) {
            the_sum();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You told it to execute 2 times every loop. `while (getwhatheywant() != 2)` and `if (getwhatheywant() == 1) {` you probably want to store the return value from `getwhatheywant()` into a variable. Then compare the value of the variable in your loop condition and your if ()

Comment: `int;` not sure why you added this.

Comment: ok I will do it thank you the int was just there by mistake

Answer (score 2):

Change your main():

```
int main()
{

    int whatTheyWant;

    while ( (whatTheyWant = getwhatheywant()) != 2) {
        if (whatTheyWant) == 1) {
            the_sum();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This stores the value from a single call to getwhattheywant() so you can first see if they're asking to quit, and if not, you can see what else they might want. Now, I'd write it slightly differently:

```
bool working = true;
while(working) {
   int choice = getWhatTheyWant();
   switch(choice) {
       case 1: the_sum(); break;
       case 2: working = false; break;
   }
}
```